# Movie about a small man climbing giant steps?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, ewoks

As a child I watched a movie in which I think I remember:

- A man (Mark Hamill, I believe) and an ewok (I think) are climbing giant steps to face a giant spider.
- If I'm not mistaken, since this was twenty+ years ago, there were fireflies in the movie  as well.

Can you help me solve this life long mystery of mine - what's the name of the movie or short film of some sort)?

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like [Caravan of Courage: An Ewok Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caravan_of_Courage:_An_Ewok_Adventure)

**Mark Hamill Lookalike**:
[image]

**Giant Staircase**:
[image]

**Giant Spider**:
[image]

**Fireflies**:
[image]

**Trailer**

Comment: As quoted by @DavRob60 for a similar question "Disclaimer : Any damage to your psychological integrity after watching, reading about or even just slightly checking for information about those movies is not my responsibility."

Comment: I quite like this film.